# How can I prevent a bottom-aligned View from jumping during layout animation?

Tags: android

Some background: I have a `ConstraintLayout` at the bottom of an activity that grows and shrinks as items are added to or removed from a `RecyclerView` inside it. The `RecyclerView` is constrained to the top left of its parent. I have another `View` inside the same parent that is constrained to the bottom right. This bottom-right `View` should always stay in the same spot; it should never appear as though it is moving while its parent container grows or shrinks vertically.

I set the container to animate changes using:

```
LayoutTransition transition = new LayoutTransition();
transition.enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
cartContainer.setLayoutTransition(transition);
```

Now, when the `RecyclerView` grows or shrinks, the parent layout animates larger or smaller accordingly, and the `RecyclerView` moves with it. The problem is that the *bottom-anchored* `View` does **not** stay in its spot while this animation happens. Instead, it jumps to its "new" position while the parent is in the middle of animating. I think this is because the child `View`'s position is defined by its relation to the *top* of the parent `ConstraintLayout`, and this new position is passed to the child right when the animation starts. What I need is for the child to appear as though it's staying in the same bottom-right spot the whole time, even though its position relative to the parent is technically changing. Any thoughts on how I can achieve this?